# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' while making build in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

When I visit localhost:3000/ than its working and login page is showing for frontend but if I visit localhost:3000/admin/login than blank page is displaying but this case is working fine using NPM start but its not working for NPM run build..

Here is the code that I am following
https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template

Comment: Please post the necessary code to reproduce the problem (a [mcve]) in the question itself, not just a link to it.

Comment: you've probably got a javascript file with a `<script>`  tag in it - common mistake by inexperienced coders

Comment: There is no way anyone can help with that unless you made absolutely zero changes after you use that template. If that's the case, you should create an issue on the git repo because the template breaks out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

try add "homepage": "/", in package,json

Comment: when open page only white space and in console show error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: already got solution , just add   "homepage": "/", in package,json

Answer (score -1):

Show your error log in your cmd or code editor for better solution.
Generally, gh-pages is not installed correctly. Type 'npm install gh-pages --save-dev' in your terminal and check again. If the problem persists then share the error log file and state the error name specifically.

Comment: Thank you for your resposne @arnab

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

react-dom.production.min.js:216 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:5000/admin/static/js/0.801a8e5c.chunk.js)
    at e.unstable_runWithPriority (http://localhost:5000/static/js/8.94fed0a3.chunk.js:2:323078)
ll @ react-dom.production.min.js:216